# how can I see how much place do I have in the heap and how can I clear it?

Tags: c, memory, linked-list, heap-memory

how can I know how much place do I have in the HEAP?
how can I clean it if I have many codes with linked list that I already ran and didn't use the free() function?

for example this code I already ran and didn't use the free() function.
how can I clean what that function made and how can I check how much place do I have now in the HEAP?

```
void main() {

int i, num,item;
LNODE* newNode;
LIST lst;
lst = makeEmptyList();
printf("Please enter the numbers of the nodes: ");
scanf("%d", &num);
printf("Please enter the value of the head: ");
scanf("%d", &item);
insertValueToHead(item, &lst);

for (i = 0; i < num-1; i++)
{
    printf("Please enter the value of the next node: ");
    scanf("%d", &item);
    newNode = createNewNode(item, lst.tail);
    AddToEndOfTheList(&lst, newNode);
}
printf("\n");
printList(&lst);
```

Comment: Release resources as soon as possible (but not sooner).

Comment: The only way to know how much memory you have allocated is to keep track of the sum of your allocations. There is no other magic way to get that answer. And note, if you do sum your allocations, it will invariably be less than the amount actually allocated due to the compiler being free to reserve more than requested for alignment purposes, minimum allocation size, etc....

Comment: The short answer is that in C, *you* are responsible for memory management. That means *you* must keep track of what you allocate, and free memory when you're done using it. There is no way to tell the runtime, "hey, clean up all the memory that I forgot to free."

Answer (score 2):

> How can I check how much place do I have now in the HEAP?

Don't worry about that.

Just ask for what you need and check the return value.

```
ptr = calloc(N, sizeof *ptr);
if (!ptr) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
//... use ptr ...
free(ptr);
```